# How to create the cryptographic key from private key for Google GeoApiContext?

Tags: java, google-geocoding-api

I have the `credentials.json` file for google cloud platform premium plan. I need to use google geocoding api to parse address. I use the `new GeoApiContext.Builder().enterpriseCredentials()` functions to pass the `client_id` and `private_key` from the `credentials.json` file.

But I receive the exception `Server error 403 forbidden` while trying to parse the address.

My question is, would I need to convert the private key (from credential json file) to something else before passing it to GeoApiContext? Or Would I need to enable google maps/geocoding api in the Google Cloud Platform to use it?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to enable Geocoding API in console if you want to use it. Also note that Google Maps Premium plan is now deprecated, so you cannot get any client ID and crypto key anymore. Use API key from your project and set corresponding restriction to API key.

Comment: Can I use GoogleClientSecrets to get the cryptographic key?

Comment: Cryptographic key was a part of Google Maps Premium plan. As I far as I know Google doesn't sell Google Maps Premium plan anymore, so there is no client id authentication anymore for Google Maps Platform. Note that Google Maps Platform and Google Cloud Platform are different products.